# How do I refer a master page Content control from a User Control?

Tags: .net, asp.net, user-controls, master-pages

I have a user control in it I want to 'inject' something into the head of a master page. I have tried to use the following approach (master page and user control mmarkup snippets)...

**MasterPage:**

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

**User Control:**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Shared/Css/Navigation.css" />
</asp:Content>
```

But that gives the error:

> Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a
>   nested master page that references a master page.

So how do I put content into the master page at runtime from a control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access a master pages content through public methods of the master page. So if I take the example from your question, you can set the link's href in the master page from your user control or page with the following modification of your code:

Introduce the link as "normal content" in the master page and give him an id so that you can access it from code behind.

```
<link id="link" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Add a property to the master page that set's the href.

```
public string LinksHref
{
     get { return link.Href; }
     set { link.Href = value; }
}
```

If you want to access this from a page you can add a MasterType directive.

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.Master" %>
```

Change the property in the controls code behind.

```
Master.LinksHref = "/Shared/Css/Navigation.css";
```

If you want to access this from a user control, you can't use the MasterType directive and have to do the casting by yourself:

```
((MasterPageClassName)Page.master).LinksHref= "/Shared/Css/Navigation.css";
```

Answer (score 5):

<strike>You can't.</strike>

By default data is designed to flow from master to user page, not vice versa.

See [Working with ASP.NET Master Pages Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx#Y483) and [How Master Pages Work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx#HowMasterPagesWork) for details.